# bash: "command not found" after installing a package in nodenv e.g. mocha, pm2

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, nodenv

As example I will use pm2. I can't run the command pm2 on my nodenv nodejs installation. It will return:

```
$ pm2 -v
$ bash: pm2: command not found
```

further:

```
$ which pm2
```

does not return anything. What am I missing?

I installed it as the documentation suggested:

```
$ yarn global add pm2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok there are several pitfalls here:

1. It looks like nodenv does not support `yarn global` package installations: [Github issue from 2018, looks like it has not been implemented](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv/issues/120)
2. If you install a package with `npm -g` option you **HAVE TO** do `nodenv rehash` in order for the command to work in bash.